# The redirect_uri URL must be absolute error for deep linking URI fbAPP_ID://

Tags: ios, facebook, ios8, facebook-oauth

Everything was working fine until today I've tried to test Safari Facebook login mechanism on my app and I started getting the following error on web browser:

`The redirect_uri URL must be absolute`.

I'm *not* using the Facebook SDK (for various reasons outside the question's context, so don't ask why) and I'm trying to open the following URL manually:

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_APP_ID&response_type=token,granted_scopes&redirect_uri=fbMY_APP_ID://&scope=user_friends,user_birthday,email,user_photos&default_audience=friends&sdk=ios`

Everything was working fine, until today where I realized that the URL isn't executing properly. I didn't change any app settings or anything. How can I complete my login flow? Yes, I need to redirect back to `fbAPP_ID://` to launch my app back when using iOS versions lower than 9.0 where native Safari isn't supported. Or is there any known way of redirecting back to the application pre-iOS 9 from external Safari? (other than me redirecting to website, *then* on my website, redirecting back to my app by force opening `fbAPP_ID://` from Javascript)

Comment: No, that is not possible. Letting it redirect back to your site, and redirect back to your app from there is the only option.

Comment: Uhm. So how does Facebook's own SDK handle this? @CBroe

Answer (score 1):

The only "redirect_uri" that works out of the box is `fbAPP_ID://authorize` , this is the one used by the Facebook SDK and anyone can use it as well.